Or-tools is not giving the best route for a matrix with floating point distances
I have this function to find the best route:
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp, routing_enums_pb2
import numpy as np

def sin_restriccion(matriz_input, indices_input):
    # Convertir el DataFrame a una matriz de distancias
    distance_matrix = matriz_input
    locations = indices_input

    # Crear el modelo de datos
    def create_data_model():
        data = {}
        data['distance_matrix'] = distance_matrix
        data['num_vehicles'] = 1
        data['depot'] = 0  # Puedes ajustar el depot según sea necesario
        return data

    # Crear el modelo de datos
    data = create_data_model()

    # Crear el gestor de rutas
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])

    # Crear el modelo de rutas
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    # Crear la función de distancia
    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

    # Definir el costo de la distancia
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    # Eliminar la restricción de retorno al depot
    routing.SetFixedCostOfAllVehicles(0)
    end_index = manager.NodeToIndex(data['depot'])
    routing.AddDisjunction([end_index], 1000000)  # Penalización alta para no regresar al depot

    # Definir parámetros de búsqueda
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
        routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
    search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 10  # Ajustar el límite de tiempo según sea necesario

    # Resolver el problema
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    # Preparar el resultado como un diccionario
    if solution:
        index = routing.Start(0)
        route_dict = {}
        step = 1
        total_distance = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            node_index = manager.IndexToNode(index)
            route_dict[step] = locations[node_index]
            next_index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            total_distance += distance_callback(index, next_index)
            index = next_index
            step += 1
        # Imprimir distancia total recorrida
        print(f'Distancia total recorrida: {total_distance}')
        return route_dict
    else:
        print('No hay solución')
        return 'No hay solución'

# Ejemplo de uso con la matriz proporcionada
matriz = np.array([
    [0.0, 22.3, 1965.4, 2108.5],
    [500.0, 0.0, 1611.7, 2130.8],  # B a A es 500 en lugar de 22.3
    [2033.1, 2080.6, 0.0, 2267.8],
    [2037.2, 2084.7, 2189.1, 0.0]
])

indices = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

# Llamada a la función
ruta_optima = sin_restriccion(matriz, indices)
print(ruta_optima)

But the result is: {1: 'A', 2: 'D', 3: 'C', 4: 'B'}
It is not too hard to see that A -> B -> C -> D is better that the result. Is there any configuration I am missing? Or its just how ortool works, not always finding the shortest solution?
I am not an expert with ortool so there may be some things I am ignoring.

the transit callback must return an int64_t, otherwise your floating point values will result to an undefind behaviour. (ed In the SWIG bridge between Python and C++, Python's floating values are converted to int64_t).
ref:
The routing RegisterTransitCallback() declaration:
https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/2c333f58a37d7c75d29a58fd772c9b3f94e2ca1c/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L654-L658
Typedef of RoutingTransitCallback:
https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/2c333f58a37d7c75d29a58fd772c9b3f94e2ca1c/ortools/constraint_solver/routing_types.h#L49-L50
In your sample you could multiply all your value per 10 to have integer values, and divide them by 10 in your print/display function...

The first answer I figure out it that ourtools doesn't work well with floats, with integers it finds the best route. Not sure about it but it works for me in this situation.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
